# How to prefill PayPal email on login form?

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am using PayPal's login (https://devtools-paypal.com/guide/openid) integration script to get consent from my website users. I would like to send email field prefilled on PayPal login page. I tried sending through query string but that doesn't work. Can we do it?

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to PayPal support team, this feature is not available as of now. They have added my request in the feature list so hopefully we can expect it in future.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using *ExpressCheckout* you can pass the `EMAIL` field with this address, however, it will be overridden depending on the browser.

The only option to force an account when logging in is to use [AdaptivePayments](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/adaptive-payments/Pay_API_Operation/%20AdaptivePayments). You would set `senderEmail` and they should not be able to change it.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your help. But I am not using ExpressCheckout and neither Classic API. I'm trying to achieve it through Rest API. The problem is that I do not see any options while I send request for login. I do not want to receive or make payments but just to get my user logged into PayPal.

Comment: By default PayPal checks for cookies from users that have been recently logged in. Any PayPal user that has been recently logged in will have their email address pre-populate. If the user has not been logged in recently or has cleared their cache and cookies this field will be blank. You cannot force this field to pre-populate for users that have no PayPal Cookies since PayPal is hosting the checkout page.

Comment: Thank you mate. Yes you are right about the cookie thing, but I forcefully wanted to prefill paypal account in the field. I contacted PayPal regarding this thing and they informed that this feature is not yet available for login page.